# Isomerization of phosphorylated 2-imino-1,3-dioxalanes into phosphorylated cyclic carbamates

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aqueous-solution, isomers, organophosphorus-compounds

I found a patent dating back to the Soviet Union. The patent number is 256764, and the patent describes the synthesis of phosphorylated cyclic carbamates. Here is a section of the patent, followed by a translation:

[image]

....A method of obtaining n-phosphoryl cyclic urethanes of the general formula [Picture] where R=alkyl, R1= H or alkyl, n=1,2, by the interaction of dichloromethyleneamides of phosphoric acid with glycols in the presence of organic bases, for example triethylamine, in organic solvent under cooling of the reaction mixture, preferrably to 0 C, is offered. In the case of using ethylene glycol or 1,2 propyleneglycol, and also 2,3- or 1,3 butyleneglycol, first, it seems, n phosphoryl 2-imino-1,3-dioxolanes are formed, which are converted by means of elevated temperatures to the desired products.

The rest of the patent gives an example of such synthesis.

It seems to me that the authors are suggesting that this reaction happens after the glycol is reacted with a dichloromethyleneamide of esters of phosphoric acid:

[image]

This looks similar to a Chapman Rearrangement, but, to my knowledge, a Chapman Rearrangement requires the presence of aromatic groups, so this isomerization reaction is not a Chapman Rearrangement. How and why does this isomerization reaction occur? What is the reaction mechanism?

Link to patent: https://patents.su/2-256764-sposob-polucheniya-n-fosforilirovannykh-ciklicheskikh-uretanov.html